# Voltage regulator vs. voltage controller

Tags: voltage-regulator, control

I frequently meet the references to **voltage-regulators** and **voltage-controllers**. However, looking at the specs I find them to perform the same function. Is there a difference between the two, or regulator/controller can be interchanged?

Comment: Please provide a few particular references (links), which you've come across.  Without that, the question is a bit broad and unclear.  In practice, "voltage controller" can mean different things in different context.

Comment: related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/174892/difference-between-dc-dc-switching-controllers-and-regulators-and-converter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A voltage regulator produces a stable output voltage that has small variance over a range of load and input conditions.

A controller is a device that monitors and modifies the state of a dynamical system. A voltage controller could be constructed to track a signal, minimize undesired signal characteristics, or even act as a voltage regulator.

Answer (score 6):

In the context of electronics: A complete regulator requires a controller. The figure below shows the block diagram for a simple voltage regulator. Here, the "controller" includes a series power component.

[image: Control reg]

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that the boxed 'regulator' would have the unregulated input and regulated output projecting outside of its boundary, while the reference value is internal?

Comment: Yes. The voltage reference ends up being internally derived from the unregulated input itself.

Comment: Ah I was hoping the internal reference would essentially be a fixed value, not derived from the unregulated. Though you might mean that in the general case, and one case is that the derivation just limits to a fixed value.

Comment: Reference voltages typically use Zener diodes or another effect involving the behavior (current x voltage) of semiconductor junctions. As if there were a regulator within a regulator, but simpler.